# Angular, local strorage how to call the keys automaticly

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to store a data in local storage so that I wont loose it when page refreshes.

There is a button in my html file that triggers this function from typescript file (The function has a paramater called 'game', which is a class that I made);

```
  handlePrice(game) {
    //HERE I CALL THE FUNCTION SETGAME OF GAMESERVICE
    this.selectedGameService.setGame(game);
  }
```

As you all can see, this function calls another function called setGame from selectedGameService. Here are the codes of that service;

```
      export class SelectedGameService {

  selectedGame: Games;  //SELECTEDGAME IS AN ELEMENT FROM GAMES CLASS
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  setGame(game: Games) {
    
    //FIST, I CHECK IF THE KEY 'theGame' IS EMPTY OR NOT AT LOCAL STORAGE
    if(localStorage.getItem('theGame') === null) {
      //IF THE KEY IS EMPTY, I SET SELECTEDGAME AS THE NEW INCOMING GAME
      //AND STORE THE GAME AT LOCAL STORAGE WITH THE KEY 'theGame'
      this.selectedGame = game;
      localStorage.setItem('theGame', JSON.stringify(this.selectedGame));
    }
    else {
      //IF THERE IS AN EXISTING GAME IN LOCAL STORAGE ALREADY
      //I SET THE SELECTEDGAME AS THE GAME IN THE KEY 'theGame'
      this.selectedGame = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('theGame'));
    }
  }
}
```

As I have checked from the applications section of F12, I can store the selectedGame in local storage. But I guess I have done a coding algorithm mistake. Because when I refresh the page, I still loose the data (not from local storage but from the page itself). I would be very happy if you can help me.

Comment: As I can see you wrote a common function to setting and getting data from localStorage. Those should be different.

Comment: What can I change them into? @Durgesh Pal

Comment: Please check the updated answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
 ngOnInit() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('theGame')) {
      this.selectedGame = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('theGame')); // use existing localstorage value
    } else {
      this.setGame(value);    // set your new game value
    }

  }

setGame(game: Games) {
   const tempGame = JSON.stringify(game);
   if (!localStorage.getItem('theGame') || (tempGame !== localStorage.getItem('theGame'))) {
       localStorage.setItem('theGame', tempGame);
       this.selectedGame = game; 
}
  }
```

Note: If the localstorage is not having any value against 'theGame' or already saved value is different from the currently passed value, set current value to localstorage. Otherwise just use this.selectedGame's current value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when I tried it, I got an error. I guess with the first line of the function we make const tempGame as a string and then tried to eualize it to a element from Game class :/ @aks44

Comment: what is the value for your input parameter 'game' ?

Comment: it has values of;
    categoryId:number;  
    title:string;       
    platform:string;    
    image:string;    
    game_type:string;